# Swift - GCM: Don't display iOS remote push notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented GCM push notifications in my iOS app. I need the notifications only for syncing with new content. That works well. But I dont want the notification to be shown to the user. How do I hide it? [image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the `content_available` parameter to `true`

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

You also need to add `remote-notifications` for `UIBackgroundMode`in your apps `Info.plist` file. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22

Comment: well i just need to Not display notification when come. Is this really the solution?

Comment: @PanMluvčí, yes it is. What you want is a silent remote notification and for this you need to do the two things stated in this answer.

Comment: well i have added 
<string>remote-notification</string>
to my info.plist file
then told my backend mate to set the content_available
.......still notifications are visible :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just for not showing the notification the notification needs to be silent. To do this you can not have any title, body or subtitle in the message.

By default, iOS will ignore a message without title, body or subtitle so the extra parameter `content_available: true` is necessary.

So, if you send this message without any title, body and subtitle but with `content_available: true` still nothing would happen.

To respond to this, the app needs permission to run a small task in the background after receiving the `scilent` notification.

To get this permission you need to edit your .plist file and add the field `Required background modes` with the value `remote-notifications`. Or you can select the project and go to the `Capabilities tab -> Background Modes -> Remote notifications`. This will add the .plist entry for you.

Now you can do a small task in the background when receiving the notification. Like parse some custom data that was in the notification payload or do some light network calls etc.

you would want to look in your AppDelegate for:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Here you can parse the `userInfo` data.